# How can i assign the current state user id to database reference and then database reference to future builder?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart

From the below code i cant access the userid of current state user without await.If i need to use await like below i need to enclose the code in a method so that there will be async. But, as the code is enclosed in a method i cant access the userid variable in databaseReference.
Can you help:

```
somemethod() async{
    FirebaseUser userid = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
}

    final **databaseReference** = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("UserProfile").child(userid.uid).("Favorites");

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: **databaseReference**.once(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DataSnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> list = [];
            for (String key in snapshot.data.value.keys) {
              list.add(snapshot.data.value[key]);
            }
```

From this code I want userid enclosed in method to be accessed in databaseReference so that I can use databaseReference in FutureBuilder to retrieve the user information.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have only 1 future builder, you need to pass function paramether on **databaseReference**.once() method

```
class yourDatabase {

   Future<dynamic> once(Function somemethod) async{
       //Now, you are caling the funcion on yourDatabase class
       dynamic returnOfSomethod = await somemethod();

       //TODO your somemethod here

   }
}
```

and to call you make this

```
somemethod() async{
    FirebaseUser userid = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
}

//Inside the build...
FutureBuilder(
   future: **databaseReference**.once(somemethod), // ! Dont place ()
   builder: () {}
)
```

hope it works!

Comment: As it is a database query I think a method can't be placed as a parameter to once(). I have tried it it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
        FirebaseUser userId; 
        Future databaseReference;
         somemethod() async{
                userid = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
                databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("UserProfile").child(userid.uid).("Favorites");    }

            @override
              Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                return FutureBuilder(
                    future: **databaseReference**.once(),
                    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DataSnapshot> snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> list = [];
                        for (String key in snapshot.data.value.keys) {
                          list.add(snapshot.data.value[key]);
                        }
```

Comment: These are the errors i got when implemented like this..                                                    
 The getter '(' isn't defined for the class 'DatabaseReference'.
Try importing the library that defines '(', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named '('.                                                                                   Expected an identifier.The method 'once' isn't defined for the class 'Future'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'once'.